# Can we read the objects stored in the ehcache of a JBOSS server from other program running in a different JBOSS server

Tags: java, jboss, ehcache

I have some objects stored in the ehcache of server1(jboss) and I would like to access this objects using a program  running in a different JBOSS server. By any case is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but you will need to make at least configuration changes to Ehcache in your server1 and will have to deploy Ehcache in your second server.

You have two options:

1. Ehcache Open Source provides [replication mechanisms](http://ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2F_ehcache_all.1.230.html%23) for doing this.
2. [BigMemory Max](http://terracotta.org/products/bigmemorymax) is a commercial solution that provides clustering for Ehcache.